# iphone and display: inline

Tags: iphone, ios, css

I'm having a weird display issue when testing a site on an iPhone4 running iOS6.

For some reason, the iPhone ignores the display: inline; rule when I click on the parent link. I've been browsing the test site using Safari developer tools, and the toggle class names are working as intended.

I'm using this piece of javascript to toggle class names on the div:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('toggle');
$(this).toggleClass('toggle_open');
});
```

The mark up looks like this:

```
<div class="toggle">
  <a href="#" class="level1"><span>Parent</span></a> 
    <div>
       <a href="#"><span>Child 1</span></a>
       <a href="#"><span>Child 2</span></a>
       <a href="#"><span>Child 3</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.toggle div { display: none; }
div.toggle, div.toggle_open  { display: inline; }
```

If I change display: inline to inline-block it works. If I remove display: inline completely it works, but then causes display issues in the browser. I want to use display: inline; so the contents of my mark up display on 1 line or 2 if required.

I'm aware I could use modinizer to create a rule for 'touch' and 'no-touch', but this seems like over kill for something that is probably a bug created by my code :)

What have I done to upset mobile Safari?

Comment: What if you used `span` instead of `div` which is inline by default?

Comment: Have tried replacing the div with a span but still doesn't display on the iPhone.

Comment: @Miszy you were right. Looked at this again this morning, and removed all divs from my markup and replaced them with span's.